# Google Places API LatLng Query

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have an array of places in LatLng, across the US. I've pulled my current location, and I want to display the places in that aforementioned list, that are within a certain distance of my current location. This is somewhat like a places radar search, except I already have my locations, I'm just trying to display relevant ones. Any advice?

*Not tied to google maps API, but it is free with a high limit of requests*

I've been exploring using, but I can't figure out how to do what I'm trying to.

[link 1](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3?csw=1#createtable)

[link 2](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#RadarSearchRequests)

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro?hl=en

There are plenty of Map APIs that allow you to enter two locations and calculate the distance between them. It is my understanding that LatLngs are an accepted format for the points you are calculating between.